# darknet mask and anchor values for yolov4

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo, darknet

In the README.md of [darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) repo https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet we have this sentence about anchor boxes:

> But you should change indexes of anchors masks= for each [yolo]-layer, so for YOLOv4 the 1st-[yolo]-layer has anchors smaller than 30x30, 2nd smaller than 60x60, 3rd remaining.

It looks like the default anchor boxes for [yolov4-sam-mish.cfg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V726wzWW1iBDcJ7uP8c0n_Y4M98lIg-C) are
12, 16, 19, 36, 40, 28, 36, 75, 76, 55, 72, 146, 142, 110, 192, 243, 459, 401

and the first yolo layer has config:

```
mask = 0,1,2
```

Do I understand correctly that this will use those anchors?

```
(12, 16), (19, 36), (40, 28)
```

If yes it seems to contradict with the statement or do I understand it incorrectly.

I'm asking because for my dataset and my image sizes (256, 96) I got those anchors from *calc_anchors* in darknet

15, 56, 22, 52, 28, 48, 23, 62, 26, 59, 39, 43, 31, 57, 29, 66, 37, 64

and trying to figure out how should I set the masks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me.

12, 16,

19, 36,

40, 28,

36, 75,

76, 55,

72, 146,

142, 110,

192, 243,

459, 401

You may leave the masks as are. She current config you show will yield higher MaP; supporting documentation here:

https://github.com/WongKinYiu/PartialResidualNetworks/issues/2